# How can I create a list of conversion rates and currency types from a table with converted values in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, distinct

I have a big table with many rows. A data example is the following:

| Currency | Value | Value_in_NOK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 100 | 800 |
| USD | 200 | 1600 |
| SEK | 120 | 108 |
| USD | 400 | 3200 |
| SEK | 240 | 216 |
| USD | 300 | 2400 |
| EUR | 15 | 150 |
| EUR | 30 | 300 |

The converted value is always in NOK.

What I want is to use a SELECT statemnet to create a distinct list of Currencies, including the NOK, with the currency rate made from the first row with the distinct Currency:

| Currency | Currency_Rate |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 8.000 |
| SEK | 0.900 |
| EUR | 10.000 |
| NOK | 1.000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a some column in your table that defines order of rows  - for example timestamp (ts)

```
select Currency, array_agg(round(Value_in_NOK/Value, 3) order by ts limit 1)[offset(0)] as Currency_Rate
from your_table
group by Currency 
union all 
select 'NOK', 1.000
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with that works perfect.

```
SELECT
      Opportunity_First_year_value_Currency,
      ARRAY_AGG(ROUND(SAFE_CAST(Opportunity_First_year_value_converted AS NUMERIC)/SAFE_CAST(Opportunity_First_year_value AS NUMERIC), 5)
      ORDER BY 
        Opportunity_Close_Date DESC 
      LIMIT
        1) [
    OFFSET
      (0)] AS Currency_Rate
    FROM
      `JOINED_Opportunity`
    WHERE 
      SAFE_CAST(Opportunity_First_year_value_converted AS NUMERIC) > 0
    GROUP BY
      Opportunity_First_year_value_Currency
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'NOK',
      1.00000
```